# Square with the minimum possible area that satisfy the given conditions

Tags: geometry, contest-math

We're given a square with integer side lenght, it is divided into 4 triangles such that all the triangle's side lenghts are integers and that no two triangles are congruent, what is the minimum possible area of the square? (picture linked below)

[image]

I tried working a bit with the two right triangles, trying to find pythagorean triples that would do the trick (since I also tried drawing the altitude of the 2 "middle" triangles) but I'm not really sure how to tackle this type of problem...

Comment: It is 16. Clearly, it can't be below 16, as a side length of 3 is impossible, and using your method, you can assign lengths nicely so that the total side length is 4.

Comment: @DonThousand It should be $576$ but I don't know how it was worked out, note that the triangles must be different from one another

Comment: It is not 576, unless you wrote the question incorrectly

Comment: @DonThousand If I wrote anything wrong I seriously apologize, on the other hand I don't see how the side lenght could be $4$, if it is, it means that the altitude of the two right triangles is $4$, meaning the other side (which is clearly smaller) must be $3$ for the hypotenuse to be integer valued, but since only $3$ does the trick you're forced into contructing two equal triangles (i.e. the two right angled ones) and thus violating the problem's request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since somehow you already knew that the answer is $576$ (side length = $24$), let us see how we can find this answer.

Let us first look at the following graph:

[image]

By your conditions, we know that $(a_1, x, b_1), (a_2, x, b_2)$ and $(a_3, x, b_3)$ form Pythagorean triples, and $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = x$. There is an additional condition that the four solid line triangles are pairwise non-congruent, but just forget it for now.

So the core of the problem is to find Pythagorean triangles with a common side $x$. Let us try a few ideas to do this:

*First.* most naively you can just write down all Pythagorean triangles, starting from smallest side lengths:

$$
(3,4,5), (6,8,10), (5,12,13), (9,12,15), (8,15,17), (12,16,20), (15,20,25), (20,21,29), \cdots
$$

This is actually doable. Since we know that all Pythagorean triangles have the form $(a(m^2-n^2), a\cdot2mn, a(m^2+n^2))$, and indeed we know by cheating that the answer is at $24$, it will not take too much time to get to the right answer. If I were you I might consider writing a program for this, if the solution is actually large.

*Second,* here is a way to increase the speed for your searching. Let $a = \min\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$. Then clearly $x > 3a_1$. This is indeed a nice restriction. From the general formula

$$
(a(m^2-n^2), a\cdot 2mn, a(m^2+n^2)), \text{ $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and exactly one of $m$ and $n$ is even}
$$

you need either (i) $m^2-n^2 > 6mn$; or (ii) $3(m^2-n^2) < 2mn$.

1. If $m^2-n^2 > 6mn$, then $m^2-6mn-n^2 > 0$ or $m > (3 + \sqrt{10})n \approx 6.16n$. The smallest Pythagorean triangles starts from $(16,65,67), (20,99,101),\cdots$.
2. If $3(m^2-n^2) < 2mn$, then $n < m < n(1+\sqrt{10})/3 \approx 1.42n$. The smallest Pythagorean triangles starts from $(7,24,25), (9,40,41), (14,48,50),\cdots$.

This should shrink our search space significantly. Anyway the minimal answer happens at $7+7+10=24$.

Comment: Well, this question appeared in last year contest of my city, I managed to pass but I remember seeing everyone quite confused about this question (it was the last one of the test so it's supposed to be challenging but no one had got it right), at first it looked very trial and error to me, so thinking back at it I was very curious if someone had a "formal" method for solving this... considering that you had 2 hours to work on 12 problems none of them should be 'too long', nonetheless, on every forum in which I posted this question I didn't recive a "crux move" or clever/quick solution, Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you have 10 minutes for this I think it is quite doable just to search through Pythagorean triples, since the answer is just 24. This means that it is fairly reasonable to have this question in a competition even if there is no "formal" method available.